# Assembler to C conversion INCF and CPFSLT

Tags: c, microchip, interrupt, pic18

Does these's two codes mean the same?

Assambler ->

```
_asm
    INCF PR4,0,ACCESS
    CPFSLT TMR4,ACCESS
_endasm
```

C ->

```
++PR4;
if (PR4 < TMR4)
   PIR3bits.TMR4IF = 1;
```

If not, how should the assambler code be translated?

Kind regards :)

Comment: What CPU/architecture is this?

Comment: it's microchip's PIC18F87J50 Compiler C18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could anyone else verify this, I think the code below is correct!

```
_asm
    INCF PR4,0,ACCESS  //PR4+1 destination WREG, Access bank
    CPFSLT TMR4,ACCESS //Compare TMR4 with contents of WREG in Access bank, Skip if TMR4 < WREG
_endasm
/* Above says: if (TMR4 <= PR4 + 1)*/
    PIR3bits.TMR4IF = 1; // Then do this line
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is no, but Im unsure how to translate it!

INCF PR4,0,ACCESS //(INCF f,d) (Increment f) (f + 1 -> d) 
"Increment PR4 Register "Working register (accumulator)" in ACCESS in other words:
Get PR +1 to WREG

```
WREG = PR +1;
```

CPFSLT TMR4,ACCESS //(CPFSLT f) (Compare f/w, skip if f< w) (f-W, skip if f < W)
Compare  TMR4 < WREG

=> skip if TMR4 < WREG
=> if TMR4 >= WREG

Should Give:

```
if (TMR4 >= WREG)
    WREG = PR4 + 1;
```

Um... right?